# No suitable constructor was found for entity type. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create this entity:

```
public class UserIBANInfo
    {
        public UserIBANInfo(string iban)
        {
            IBAN = iban;
        }

        [Key]
        public string IBAN { get; set; }
    }
```

for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserIBANInfos
(
IBAN CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

but when I try doing so I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'UserIBANInfo'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
    Cannot bind 'iban' in 'UserIBANInfo(string iban)'
```

Comment: U need a constructor without parameters.

Comment: @Ivailo while your solution solves the problem it does not exactly match [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors). I think what would work as well would be if you changed the casing of parameter to constructor to `iBAN`, hence matching Pascal-cased `IBAN` property name to camel-case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constructor without parameters before the actual constructor